# gson.toJson setting non-empty String value from Object to empty/NULL in Json

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to convert a `Java Object` to `Json` using `Gson API`. However sometimes the String value in the **Object** is converted to **empty**/**NULL** in `Json` output.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
       private long longValue = 9;
       private String stringValue = "my string";
       // .......
}
```

I'm using `Gson` to convert an `Object` of MyClass to `Json`

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(obj);
println jsonStr;
```

Intermittently the value of variable 'stringValue' is set to empty/NULL.

```
{"longValue": 9, "stringValue": ""}
```

My question is why `Gson` is setting **empty/NULL** values in the `Json` object. I'm quite sure the input `Object` does not have **empty/NULL** `String`.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: I just ran your code many times, and never saw this issue. Are you sure `stringValue` is not being set to the empty String somewhere? Could you try to make the field `final` to make sure it cannot be changed after being set to the initial value?

Comment: sorry for delayed acknowledgement ... there is actually no problem with the output json, its just one my crazy client, who uses my WS, raised this false alarm .. damn! I wasted much time!

Thanks @andersschuller appreciate your efforts